# TERM environment variable not set

Tags: linux, sh

I have a file.sh with this, when run show : TERM environment variable not set.

```
smbmount //172.16.44.9/APPS/Interfas/HERRAM/sc5 /mnt/siscont5 -o 
iocharset=utf8,username=backup,password=backup2011,r

if [ -f /mnt/siscont5/HER.TXT ]; then
    echo "No puedo actualizar ahora"
    umount /mnt/siscont5
else 
    if [ ! -f /home/emni/siscont5/S5.TXT ]; then
        echo "Puedo actualizar... "
        touch /home/emni/siscont5/HER.TXT
        touch /mnt/siscont5/SC5.TXT
        mv -f /home/emni/siscont5/CCORPOSD.DBF /mnt/siscont5
        mv -f /home/emni/siscont5/CCTRASD.DBF /mnt/siscont5
        rm /mnt/siscont5/SC5.TXT
        rm /home/emni/siscont5/HER.TXT
        echo "La actualizacion ha sido realizada..."
    else
        echo "No puedo actualizar ahora: Interfaz exportando..."
    fi
fi
umount /mnt/siscont5
echo "/mnt/siscont5 desmontada..."
```

Comment: the server is runing ok, Cron call this .sh every 2 minutes, but sometimes show TERM environment variable not set, then .sh dont do nothing.

Comment: I have in the same server some .sh that Cron call in diferent interval of time.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can see if it's really not *set*. Run the command `set | grep TERM`.

If not, you can set it like that:
`export TERM=xterm`

Answer (score 78):

Using a terminal command i.e. "clear", in a script called from cron (no terminal) will trigger this error message.  In your particular script, the smbmount command expects a terminal in which case the work-arounds above are appropriate.

Comment: this was the issue for me

Comment: `clear` (or other terminal command) if added to `.bashrc` or other scripts called from `.bashrc`, will result to same.

Comment: had a clear it in the motd - how could I ever solve this without finding this post!

Comment: Aaah, that was it, thank you! Now I'd like to find a command which tells me that I am in a terminal? Preferable usable with Python?

Comment: py:  os.environ.get("TERM")  bash:  $TERM

Comment: Indeed! In Python TERM has the value None when the script is started from e.g. cron job. TERM is e.g. xterm-256color when started from a terminal. So to clear a terminal without annoying error message in cron jobs is:
if os.environ.get("TERM") is not None:  os.system("clear")

Answer (score 6):

You've answered the question with this statement:

> Cron calls this `.sh` every 2 minutes

Cron does not run in a terminal, so why would you expect one to be set?

The most common reason for getting this error message is because the script attempts to source the user's `.profile` which does not check that it's running in a terminal before doing something tty related. Workarounds include using a shebang line like:

#!/bin/bash -p

Which causes the sourcing of system-level profile scripts which (one hopes) does not attempt to do anything too silly and will have guards around code that depends on being run from a terminal.

If this is the entirety of the script, then the `TERM` error is coming from something *other* than the plain content of the script.

Comment: other .sh is calling by cron in diferent interval of time, when this error appear reboot comand not work...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm finding it very difficult to understand what you're saying in these comments. the shebang line mentioned should be at the start of the script - the very first line. nothing is mentioned about another script, and if reboot is not working, but you're running as root, then you have something else wrong with the system.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace :

> `export TERM=xterm`

with :

> `export TERM=linux`

It works even in kernel with virgin system.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: On Debian 10 by adding "EXPORT TERM=xterm" on the Script executed by CRONTAB (root) but executed as www-data.

$ crontab -e

```
*/15 * * * * /bin/su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/todos.sh'
```

FILE=/usr/local/bin/todos.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -p
export TERM=xterm && cd /var/www/dokuwiki/data/pages && clear && grep -r -h '|(TO-DO)' > /var/www/todos.txt && chmod 664 /var/www/todos.txt && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/todos.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Docker PowerShell image set the environment variable for the terminal like this with the *-e* flag

```
docker run -i -e "TERM=xterm" mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
```