# TERM environemt varaible not set error Python

Tags: python, variables

Good day. I am using a repl server with Python 3.1.1. I am on Linux. I am aware of

> [TERM environment variable not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242025/term-environment-variable-not-set)

However, when I *do* put `set | grep TERM` or `export TERM=xterm`, it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 75
    set | grep TERM
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also want to clear my shell window.

UPDATE: 
My screen clearing code is from:

> [how to clear the screen in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: That's a shell pipeline, not Python code.

Comment: Ohhhh... Well, I want to have the screen cleared when the user inputs 'ok'. Screen clearing code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python.

Comment: Python 3.1.1? That's almost a decade out of date. You should get a newer Python if at all possible.

Comment: @user2357112 I am using repl.it.

Comment: repl.it should have 3.6.1.

Comment: @user2357112 Repl.it doesn't though.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run bash code inside python, which is invalid syntax.

To achieve the same effect try

```
import os
os.environ.get('TERM', '')
```

To set an environment variable from python try

```
import os
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm'
```

But ideally set that from bash.

Comment: When I do this, it says `'foo': unknown terminal type.` Any idea why?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. I thought you knew what value you wanted `TERM` to have. Try `os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm'`? Edited my answer accordingly