# Installing pi-hole in Docker Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Ubuntu based docker container. I am trying to install pi-hole in it. The commands for installation are in my base.dockerfile. The commands are: 
    FROM ubuntu:latest
        # Commands for pi-hole
        RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
        RUN echo -e "\nexport TERM=xterm" >> ~/.bashrc

```
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        && curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash

    RUN \
        apt-get update --fix-missing\
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

However, I am getting the following error:
[image]

Extracted text from the image:

```
> Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe
> amd64 Packages [4235 B] Fetched 4201 kB in 1s (3770 kB/s) Reading
> package lists... Reading package lists... Building dependency tree...
> Reading state information... curl is already the newest version
> (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38
> not upgraded.
> 
>   [✓] Root user check
> 
>         .;;,.
>         .ccccc:,.
>          :cccclll:.      ..,,
>           :ccccclll.   ;ooodc
>            'ccll:;ll .oooodc
>              .;cll.;;looo:.
>                  .. ','.
>                 .',,,,,,'.
>               .',,,,,,,,,,.
>             .',,,,,,,,,,,,....
>           ....''',,,,,,,'.......
>         .........  ....  .........
>         ..........      ..........
>         ..........      ..........
>         .........  ....  .........
>           ........,,,,,,,'......
>             ....',,,,,,,,,,,,.
>                .',,,,,,,,,'.
>                 .',,,,,,'.
>                   ..'''.
> 
>   [✓] Disk space check   [✓] Update local cache of available packages
> 
>   [✗] Checking apt-get for upgraded packages
>       Kernel update detected. If the install fails, please reboot and try again   [i] Installer Dependency checks...   [i] Checking for
> apt-utils (will be installed)   [i] Checking for dialog (will be
> installed)   [✓] Checking for debconf   [i] Checking for dhcpcd5 (will
> be installed)   [i] Checking for git (will be installed)   [i]
> Checking for iproute2 (will be installed)   [i] Checking for whiptail
> (will be installed) TERM environment variable needs set. The command
> '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     curl     && curl
> -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am a bit confused as I am pretty new to this.

Any suggestions or leads are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you extract the text content from that PNG file, and replace the image with that?  Including the entire Dockerfile (and especially the `FROM` line) would be helpful too.

Comment: There's an image for pihole already, why create a new one? Can you use their Dockerfile instead?

Comment: I have to somehow install pi-hole in the above image. Is there any other way to achieve this? I am really confused

Comment: @BMitch Which one do you talk about?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [typical script error](https://github.com/Azure/acs-demos/issues/77) in virtual environments that applies to Docker containers, too. Please try the solutions from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242025/term-environment-variable-not-set):

One of these:

- Run the command `set | grep TERM`
- Run `export TERM=xterm`
- Run `export TERM=linux`

Comment: Seems that you already set `export TERM=xterm` in the dockerfile (second line in the section "Commands for pi-hole"), you can try changing this

Comment: I tried but somehow the commands dont work for me. I am not sure what is wrong with the code.