# getting the error "TERM environment variable not set" when running a bash script from Java process builder

Tags: java, bash

I have a bash script that runs fine from the terminal, but when I attempt to execute it from my Java program using ProcessBuilder it fails with `TERM environment variable not set`:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "./my_script", "my_param");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.directory("../../");
 Process p = pb.start();
 ...
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16242025/4828060) which reports the same problem when running a bash script, however in my case this **only happens when I run it from Java ProcessBuilder**. I am curious to understand why.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: How is your Java program started? From the terminal or as a service or daemon?

Comment: ProcessBuilder *can* change the environment of the program it starts, but it defaults to the environment of the parent process (the JVM itself), which is normal practice for all UNIX programs.

Comment: So, look at the environment variables set for your JVM. Keep in mind, though, that TERM doesn't make *sense* for services or cron jobs since they don't run in a terminal at all, so there's no such thing as a terminal type for them.

Comment: The duplicate you link really is a duplicate. The parent JVM plays the same role here (as a parent process that doesn't have TERM set) that cron does there. If that's not true, edit to show evidence to that effect, ping me, and I'll reopen.