# Strange behavior when running top through ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

It's strange that neither

```
ssh user@192.168.1.59 bash -c "top"
```

nor

```
ssh user@192.168.1.59 "top"
```

works as expected, whereas both

```
ssh user@192.168.1.59 "ls"
```

and

```
ssh user@192.168.1.59 bash -c "ls"
```

work well.

Here is the error message\output for the former command.

```
TERM environment variable not set.
```

I searched and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242025/term-environment-variable-not-set).

As per the said post, there is an `answer` shed some light on this matter.

> You can see if it's really not set. Run the command set | grep TERM.
> If not, you can set it like that: export TERM=xterm

I tried

```
ssh user@192.168.1.59 bash -c "set | grep TERM;top"
```

, and the output is

```
TERM=dumb
TERM environment variable not set.
```

, which is in my expectation.

Then I try to set `XTERM` as what the post told me, but it does not work. I am stuck again.
Here is my command to set `XTERM` and run `top`:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.59 bash -c "export TERM=xterm-256color; top"
```

Here is the output for the above command:

```
declare -x DISPLAY="localhost:13.0"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_ALL="C"
#...
TERM environment variable not set.
```

Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Questions that are about how UNIX tools work, as opposed to about software development per se, are a better fit for [unix.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's the difference between writing to standard output (a stream) and trying to write directly to the terminal (allowing finer grained cursor control, for example).

Comment: @chepner Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: You can't possibly have gotten the output you describe from the command you posted. Are you sure that you did not accidentally write a semicolon after the `export`? The reason is that you get on the output a list of your environment, and the commands you have posted here don't generate such a list.

Comment: BTW, the usual way to set an environment on the remote side, is to create a file `~/.ssh/environment` which contains just `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: @user1934428 No, I wrote the semicolon after the `export` on purpose. And I run `export TERM=xterm-256color; echo $TERM` in local `bash` just now, the output is `xterm-256color`. If I miss something, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you could post in your comment a screenshot....

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `Unix & Linux` is very slow. And you see there are many questions about `bash` 、`ssh` on StackOverflow. So I think it's all right to do so.

Comment: Asking questions here when they belong there is part of _why_ it's so slow over there.

Comment: ...and yes, there are lots of questions that are on-topic about bash here, specifically those asking how to _write bash scripts_; which is software development. Merely _using_ bash is not software development. Same for ssh: A question that's specific to automating ssh in a script is software development and on-topic; whereas a question about using ssh manually as a human operator is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `-t` option to allocate a pseudo-terminal for the ssh session.
For example

```
ssh -t user@192.168.1.59 top
```

Comment: Yup, it works! Thank you for the rapid reply. Two more questions arise:1. why `ssh user@192.168.1.59 "ls" ` works, whereas `ssh user@192.168.1.59 "top"` does not? 2. why `ssh user@192.168.1.59 bash -c "***export TERM=xterm-256color***; top"` does not work, you see I set `TERM` indeed.

Comment: Use `top -n 1`. `-n` parm will tell top make a list of processes one time instead of continuous output from top which is why it never seems to work in your case.

Comment: @John, `ls` and `top` are very unlike each other: the former doesn't need any kind of terminal interaction; the latter is explicitly a tool for display to human users, and is expected to take enough control over the terminal to do things like rewriting in-place (the alternative that's more like `ls` is `ps`)

Comment: `ssh -t user@192.168.1.59 "top -n 1"` I just tried it out and it works great for me

Comment: @GoinOff Yup, both `ssh -t user@192.168.1.59 "top -n 1"` and `ssh -t user@192.168.1.59 "top"` work well. The problem is I did not add `-t` option.